# Does Plesk Limit the amount of subscriptions/domains

Tags: redhat, plesk, parallels

I'm wondering what is the maximum amount of sites/subscriptions that a plesk install can allow? Is it dependent on diskspace?
The version we have installed is psa-11.0.9-rhel6.build110120608.16.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Think, it mostly depend on OS/file system settings and settings of such services like apache, nginx, mysql and postfix. I have seen several articles in parallels knowledge base which are describing tweaks for increasing maximum amount of domains. For example:

http://kb.parallels.com/113974

http://kb.parallels.com/115139

http://kb.parallels.com/769

Obliviously there is should be a limit caused by internal software design. I know that there are plesks with ~1000 of domains and ~5000 of mailboxes. By the way, I know that there is Parallels Plesk Automation, it's a product for middle hosters and it's allows divide hosting services by different servers, which also allow to increase amounts of domains.

May be it's prefer to ask on http://serverfault.com, may be there are guys which are faced with big stand-alone plesk servers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the number of domains you can have, depending on your license. On one of my cloud servers, the limit is 30 because that's what my license allows.